# Codeigniter passing multiple parameters to controller from view?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a system that is outputting a number of images, with a A link next to them to set them as the album cover.

I have multiple albums, and in my database have a field called "is_feature" that is set to 1 if the image is the cover, and 0 if it isnt.

I don't know the best way of selecting the image, i originally outputted something like below;

```
<a href="/admin/set_photo/'.$image_id.'" title="Set this photo as the feature photo">Set</a>
```

(image_id is the images id obviously), this function would call the model and set all other photos "is_feature" field to 0, and this photos "is_feature" to 1.

The problem is it is wiping all the other album features as well. I almost need to pass to variables in the A link, the first being the id of the image, the second being the id of the album, then my model function can only set "is_feature" to 0 where album_id = the id of the album passed.

Is there anyway to pass two variables like this? Or am i going about this in totally the wrong way?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can set the values in the URL as query parameters

```php
<a href="/admin/set_photo?var1=<?= $image_id;?>&var2=<?= $size;?>"
   title="Set this photo as the feature photo"> Set </a>
```

Which you can retrieve in the controller

```php
$image_id = $this->input->get('var1');
$image_size = $this->input->get('var2');
```

Comment: Yes, this is pretty much it! Only im not using query strings. I had no idea you could pass multiple parameters via the url, im a codeigniter newbie and from the documentation i thought it was limited to one argument (ie http://controller/function/argument) Thanks for pointing me in the right direction, really appreciated it.

Answer (score 5):

Uh what? You can pass whatever you need.

```
$data = array(
               'title' => 'My Title',
               'heading' => 'My Heading',
               'message' => 'My Message'
          );

$this->load->view('blogview', $data);
```

Comment: No, i'm aware you can pass information from the controller to the view via an array, what i wanted to do is pass multiple parameters to a controller, from the view using A link. Sorry my question is worded a bit badly.

Comment: The question is passing parameters from view to controller not the controller to view

Answer (score 0):

Depending upon **data type** as string or as array, there are 3 ways of passing data (You can use any of them explained below, BASED upon YOUR REQUIREMENT):

### **Through View**

```
  //For data you collected through POST method from FORM, collect them as array
        $data=array(
            'employee_name' => $this->input->post('emp_name'),
            'employee_email' => $this->input->post('emp_email'),
            'employee_password' => $this->input->post('emp_password')
             );

$this->load-> view(''mynextpage", $data)
```

### **Through Controller**

```
redirect('controller_name/index'.$valueofcustomer);
OR
redirect(base_url()."controller_name/index/".$valueofcustomer);



//then in your 'view', you can access value of customer like this:
$v_o_c = $this->uri->segment(3); 
echo "your value is " .$v_o_c;
```

### **Through Session**

```
$data = array(
                'user_name' => $user_name,
                'is_logged_in' => true
            );

$this->session->set_userdata($data); //set the session
redirect('another_controller/index'); 

//then access those in another_controller like this:
$in = $this->session->set_userdata('$data');

Note: Session data will available only for redirect and lost on next page request
```